# Javascript Adding All Values To variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var temp=document.getElementById("col").value;
     var temp2=temp.split("%");
     for(i=0;i<col.length;i++) {         
         val = temp2[0]+temp2[1]+temp2[2];
         /* ... */
     }
</script>
```

I have the above code, instead of

```
val = temp2[0]+temp2[1]+temp2[2];
```

Could it be possible to store all array values into val variable? I mean a generic way of adding values to val instead of specifying array position?

Thanks

Comment: What's the purpose of the splitting the string and then combine it again? If you just want to get rid of the `%`, then use `var val = temp.replace(/%/g, '')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try

```
temp2.join(""); // join elements with no delimiter
```

Comment: This looks a very simple approach.

Comment: @Polappan: I would still like to stress Felix Kling's comment to your question as splitting and joining is more complicated than just removing all `%`s.

Answer (score 2):

Would be great to know what you want to do

assuming col contains 1%2%3%4

`var val = document.getElementById("col").value.split("%").join("");`

val now contains 1234

`var val = document.getElementById("col").value.replace(/\%/g,"");`

val now contains 1234

```
var temp = document.getElementById("col").value.split("%");
var val = 0;
for (var i=0;i<temp.length;i++) val += parseInt(temp[i],10);
```

val now contains 10

Comment: I would suggest using `parseInt(..., 10)` because some numbers imply other bases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the slice function:

```
val = temp2.slice(0, 3);
```

Comment: `val = temp2.slice(0, 3);` instead of 0,3, could it be possible to have generic as sometimes array could contain many values.

Comment: oh, I thought you only wanted to have the first three elements. In this case, you could either use `val = temp2.slice(0, temp2.length);` or @pimvdb 's answer

Comment: And this is different from the much simpler temp2.join("") as posted by pimvdb how?

Comment: Yes this is simple `temp2.join("")`

Answer (score 0):

```
var sumall = function(a, b) {return a + b}
var s = [1,2,3,4,5].reduce(sumall)
```

Comment: That is a very new function (JS 1.8, i.e. IE9) https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: @mplungjan - not so new, actually, it is supported in all modern browsers. Besides, it is quite easy to implement in older browsers. You provided a link with code snippet,actually)))

Comment: I for one cannot run IE9 so it is too new for at least one of my browsers.

Comment: @mplungjan Once again, it easy to implement in any browser. And use anytime you need it.

Comment: Sure. but worth mentioning, no?